# Intellij Idea execute old code when Im debugging

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin

I am using intellij and When I try to execute new code, and I try to debug it, the project is executing the old code. I tried to rebuild the project, delete the caches, the invalidate and restart, I also tried to reinstall the ide and I still having the problem. I tried to execute on another computer and its still there. And I also logging on my partner pc and When I tried there its still the problem there and when my partner execute this code the debugger its working good. So we dont know if the problem is from my company user or something like that.

Comment: might be using an old code while debugging but assuming it is a new one, happens sometimes.

Comment: If possible, please show your code. If not, I just can say, your code is different with your partner. Admit it!

Comment: Its confidential. Its the same code, its from a repository and we did the checkout from the same branch

Comment: Try to remove your run configuration and make a new one: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html

Comment: See the Run console first line (click to expand it). Compare the classpath between the working  system and the system where it doesn't work. The order can be incorrect, for example you may have a jar with older code version first in the classpath which overrides the most recent project code.

Comment: So if I remove the dependencies from maven could work? Or could be a problem of my user on git